# Yii2 framework - error 403 при работе с изображениями

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Здравствуйте, участники сообщества!
Хотел бы обратиться к вам вот с каким вопросом: В Yii2 framework для использования css стилей и js скриптов нужно задать, так называемый, комплект ресурсов, чтобы приложение имело возможность их использовать. А что делать с изображениями? Мне не понятно как получить доступ на их использование..

Вот что подразумевается под комплектом ресурсов:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/bootstrap-social-gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css',
        'css/flexslider.css',
        'css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css',
        'css/justified-nav.css',
        'css/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'scripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js',
        'scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js',
        'scripts/modernizr.js',
        'https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js',
        'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: А вам какое изображение нужно показать? Можете просто положить его на сайт и выводить по прямой ссылке, такой вариант подойдет?

Comment: Мне нужно показать изображение, которое должно находиться в какой-нибудь директории веб-приложения. Обращение к изображению напрямую приводит к ошибке доступа.

Comment: А если положить изображение в ту же папку, что и index.php, будет ошибка доступа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то комплекты ресурсов в Yii2 не для публикации изображений =)
Правда возможна публикация внутренней директории через public $sourcePath и потом использование изображения по относительному пути, но это не для вашего случая.

У вас есть два варианта.

1) Класть самим изображения в web. И потом просто использовать относительный путь src="/example.jpg"

2) Хранить изображения где и как угодно и отдавать через действие контроллера. Например контроллер site действие примерно такого типа

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    $image = ImageModel::findOne($id);
    $filePath = Yii::$app->imageComponent->getFileDirPath($image->hash) 
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image->hash . '.' . $image->type;

    return \Yii::$app->response->sendFile($filePath, "$image->name.$image->type");
}
```

конечно, нужно самим написать компонент imageComponent.. и по хорошему нужно в нем предусмотреть генерацию thumbnails..
соответственно путь к картинке будет src="/site/download?id=7"

...подозреваю, знаний пока мало, наверное стоит использовать готовые расширения типа https://github.com/CostaRico/yii2-images